# Is it possible for the international graduate student to take the exam of professional courses?

Tags: graduate-school, university

I would like to know whether the international graduate student can also take the exam of professional courses such as CPA,or CFA?Are there any legal restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in Japan, there are many people that go to Guam to take the CPA. Essentially anybody can do it, but if you graduate from an American University, there are some modules that you do not need to take, pretty much like the Japanese CPA.